# Multiple conditioning column creation to existing dataframe

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to modeling in Python, switching from Excel in an attempt to save time with loads of data. I'm enormously frustrated with one thing, in particular, that seems like it should be the easiest thing;

Problem:
I'm trying to create new multi-conditional columns in my existing df from existing columns. I have no problem with one condition,

e.g.

```
df['bsig'] = np.where(df['roc'] == eu20['mom30h'],1,0)
```

but I can't seem to figure out multiple conditions. I've tried;

```
np.where(np.logical_and(df['bsig']==1, df['c+1']>df['Close'])),1,0
np.where(np.logical_and(df['bsig']==1, df['c+1']>df['Close']).all()),1,0

np.where(df['bsig'] ==1) and np.where(df['c+1']>df['Close']),1,0
```

Among a range of errors I get, "Length of values (3) does not match the length of index (5004)" is the most common.

Does anyone feel like helping me?

Comment: Hi, it might help if you can give us an (copy-paste-able) example/subset of the data so we can replicate the issue and work out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my comment being said I think there is an easy fix for your issue: Chain conditions using `&` and `|`.

Here is some example code showing this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(1)

D = {"A": [random.randint(1,6) for x in range(4)],
     "B": [random.randint(1,6) for x in range(4)],
     "C": [random.randint(1,6) for x in range(4)]}

df = pd.DataFrame(D)

df["D"] = np.where( (df["A"] == df["B"]), 1, 0)

df["E"] = np.where( (df["A"] == df["B"]) & (df["B"]  > df["C"]) , 1, 0)

df["F"] = np.where( (df["A"] <= df["B"]) | (df["B"] != df["C"]) & (df["B"] != df["C"]) , 1, 0)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your help. I had tried changing the "and" for an "&" many times, however, what was wrong was probably my overall parentheses layout.

fix was:

np.where( (df['bsig'] ==1) & (df['c+1'] > df['Close'] ) ,1,0)

Have a great weekend!